# getting a pointer or reference to the base class c++

Tags: c++, oop, type-conversion

Suppose I have 3 classes `class BaseA`, `class BaseB` and `class DerivedC` (all forward delcared).

```
class BaseA
{
public:
    BaseA();
    BaseA(const BaseB&);
};
```

and

```
class BaseB
{
public:
    BaseB();
    BaseB(const BaseA&);
};
```

As you can see, class A and B are "symmetrically compatible" (a phrase I invented) so that each can be converted to the other.

```
class DerivedC: virtual BaseA, virtual BaseB
{
public:
    DerivedC();
    DerivedC(const BaseA &a): BaseA(a), BaseB(a) {};
    DerivedC(const BaseB &b): BaseA(b), BaseB(b) {};

    void A() {
        (BaseA)*this = (BaseB)*this;
    };
};
```

I was wondering if there was a more elegant/efficient way to do this. I want to set the BaseA part of DerivedC equal to the BaseB part of DerivedC, however these classes are low level and used at a high frequency, and I prefer to only use classes at a high level as a last resort.

**Edit:** The conversion between A and B involves arctangents and sqrts (can you guess what it is?). But I want to get away from the casts.

**Edit:** The base classes have some get-sets and operators which should be inherited.

Comment: are you implementing an adapter pattern? some kind of messaging? It's hard to tell what you need with the generic type names. If BaseA and BaseB are plain old data classes, the `operator=` operation should be pretty fast.

Comment: The actual application of these constructs involves classes containing two variables with get and set functions for each. It is applied as a Vector class (containing magnitude and direction component) and a Point class (containing x and y component). The derived is used as a way to get quick access to both. Without having to convert repeatedly

Answer (score 1):

Why not just this:

```
struct Point { float x,y; };
struct Vector { float mag,theta; };
struct PointVector {
  PointVector(const Point& p_,const Vector& v_):p(p_),v(v_) {}
  Point p;
  Vector v;
};
```

Comment: This would work if everything were public, but these classes have operator overloads and getset functions that are inherited

Comment: if you're using a commercial or open source vector library, you should add that in the question. If it's in-house, maybe show a bit more detail in the base classes.